# --disable-web-security flag deprecated in Chrome 35.0.1916.114 m?

Tags: google-chrome

The flag `--disable-web-security` that i used to allow cross domain request from local page seems doesn't work in Chrome version 35.0.1916.114 m?

Could you confirm ?

Answer (score 0):

I am using chrome stable 35.0.1916.153 m and --disable-web-security works for me.

[image]

If you are unable to use it, follow these steps (reposting my similar answer):

Kill chome from task Manager First. In Windows - Right Click (or Shift+right click, incase of taskbar) on Chrome Icon. Select Properties. In "Target" textbox, add --disable-web-security flag.

So text in textbox should look like

"C:\Users\njadhav\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome SxS\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security

Click Ok and launch chrome.